# CMake failing on simple test program

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm on Xubuntu 19.10 and trying to compile a program. It was working a couple of days ago, but after restarting my computer, for some reason my `build` directory disappeared. I'm trying to remake it but things are failing on `cmake ..`. The error I'm getting is

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.2.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

"/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: /home/bojohnson/Documents/MagPhyxP/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_77531/fast"
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/bojohnson/Documents/MagPhyxP/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTC_77531/fast" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/bojohnson/Documents/MagPhyxP/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/bojohnson/Documents/MagPhyxP/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I've tried multiple other suggestions I've found for this problem, such as `set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE "STATIC_LIBRARY")` or `SET (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)` and
`SET (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)` but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I was placing those items at the bottom in the wrong part of the `CMakeLists.txt` file. The `SET (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)` and `SET (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)` lines needed to be placed before the `project()` line.